# Failing to call a controller action in a different project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, service, routes

I have an Admin project and a Payment project.

Payment project has a Configuration Controller that I want to use like an API to get data from:

```
namespace DSSL.DCWEB.Web.Gateway.Controllers
{
    public class PaymentConfigurationController : DCWEBControllerBase
    {
        public PaymentConfigurationController()
        {
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IDictionary<string, string> GetSettings()
        {
            var test = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return test;
        }
```

I want to call this action from a controller in the Admin website:

```
var resultTest = RedirectToAction("GetSettings", "PaymentConfiguration");
```

In the Admin Startup.cs I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "GatewayConfiguration",
      "PaymentConfiguration/GetSettings",
      new { controller = "PaymentConfiguration", action = "GetSettings" },null,
      new[] { "Payment.Controllers" }
 );
```

Currently the call in the Admin Controller doesnt throw an error and just doesn't do anything.

Comment: These are two separate sites? If so, you'll have to enable CORS in the Admin application in order for your browser to do a cross origin request. The alternative would be to create a HTTP Web Request object in server side code to redirect to the Admin site.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTTP Request to consume web api ,using [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44348/api/values"))
    {
        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //now you can deserialize the response to object 
    }
}
```

See code samples from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-web-apis-in-asp-net-core-mvc-application/) and [here](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-consume-api/) .

If the web applications are from different domain , you should enable `Cross-Origin Requests (CORS)` , browser security prevents a web page from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the web page:

[Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I tried the first suggestion but didn't realise about CORS, so I'll get that implemented today.

Comment: Any update ? feel free to let me know if any further question ,

Comment: Enabling Cors was required but the other issue I also had was running one of the projects in Docker and the other locally and got 'Unable to assign requested address' but when running both locally it now works! Cheers